# How to sort a List of String according to a Double score that is stored?

Tags: java, list, file, sorting, comparator

Here is my problem: I have to display a set of Nested structures and I have a problem. I am supposed to write to a file a queries, with associated result file, number of time the query appears in the file, and a score that is calculated. Only problem is that I have to sort the displayed result by score and not by alphabetical order ( which is what I am doing right now ). I have no idea what to use or where to start so I'd be incredibly happy if I could get some help. Here is the function:

```
public static void asNestedArrayQueries(List<String> elements, TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>> actual, TreeMap<String, Integer> countMap, Writer writer, int level)
        throws IOException {
    TreeMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new TreeMap< String, Integer>();
    int counter=0, counterOfFiles=0;
    double divider=0;
    elements.sort( Comparator.comparing( String::toString ) ); 
    writer.write("{\n");
    for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++) {
        counter++;
        indent(writer, 1);
        writer.write("\"" + elements.get(i) + "\": [\n");   
        String[] words = elements.get(i).split(" ");
        counterOfFiles=0;
        for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++) {
            if(actual.containsKey(words[j])){
                for(String keyTwo : actual.get(words[j]).keySet()) {
                    if(!resultMap.containsKey(keyTwo)) {
                        resultMap.put(keyTwo, actual.get(words[j]).get(keyTwo).size());
                    }
                    else if(resultMap.containsKey(keyTwo)){
                        resultMap.put(keyTwo, resultMap.get(keyTwo)+actual.get(words[j]).get(keyTwo).size());
                    }
                    System.out.println(resultMap);
                    divider = countMap.get(keyTwo);
                }
            }
        }
        for(String key : resultMap.keySet()) {
            double score = resultMap.get(key)/divider;
            String formatted;
            counterOfFiles++;
            indent(writer, 2);
            writer.write("{\n");
            indent(writer, 3);
            writer.write("\"where\": \"" + key + "\",\n");
            indent(writer, 3);
            writer.write("\"count\": " + resultMap.get(key) + ",\n");
            indent(writer, 3);
            formatted = String.format(Locale.US, "%.8f", score);
            writer.write("\"score\": " + formatted + "\n");
            if(counterOfFiles<resultMap.keySet().size()) {
                indent(writer, 2);
                writer.write("},\n");
            }
            else {
                indent(writer, 2);
                writer.write("}\n");
            }
        }
        if(counter<elements.size()) {
            indent(writer, 1);
            writer.write("],\n");
        }
        else {
            indent(writer, 1);
            writer.write("]\n");
        }
        resultMap.clear();
    }
    writer.write("}");
    elements.clear();
}
```

Comment: So the score is the value of the resultMap, and the key is the string? And what you want to do is print resultMap in a sorted order based on the value?

Comment: The score is the value of resultMap divided by a value that is in countMap. The key of result map is the String yes. I want to print resultMap in a sorted order based on the score

Comment: Can you construct an example call to "asNestedArrayQueries" so I know how it looks ? Like if u would write an unit test for it

Comment: Here is what it is printing, on the left, compared to what it is supposed to output, on the right. https://imgur.com/a/5vxiytU

Comment: This shows it is actually sorting alphabetically with the "where" criteria. I would like to sort according to the "score" criteria

Comment: What if you swap keys with values? So the key is the "score" (I know it needs to be divided, but that is irrelevant since it is a constant value it is divided with throughout the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorting Map but it may work for TreeMap as well. You can sort it by value via creating custom Comparator -> Collections.sort(list, customComparator) .
Here is example for a simple Map with one Key and one Value. Yes the Value used here is String, but it can be Integer as well for your score:

```
Map<Integer, String> firstMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> secondMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
firstMap.put(1, "name");
firstMap.put(2, "year");
firstMap.put(3, "month");
firstMap.put(4, "day");

secondMap = sortByComparator(firstMap, true);
```

the method:

```
 /**
     * This method sorts ConcurrentHashMap variable by order
     * @param unsortedMap - the ConcurrentHashMap to sort
     * @param order       - true for descending order, false for ascending
     * @return sorted ConcurrentHashMap variable
     */
    private static Map<Integer, String> sortByComparator(Map<Integer, String> unsortedMap, final boolean order) {
        List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>(unsortedMap.entrySet());

        // Sorting the list based on values via CUSTOM COMPARATOR
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, String> o1,
                               Map.Entry<Integer, String> o2) {
                if (order) {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                } else {
                    return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
                }
            }
        });

        // Maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
        Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : list) {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }
```